# failed to load wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Tags: ajax

I'm getting this strange issue. Everything was working fine last day. Now suddenly none of my ajax requests work. The problem is (i found that in firebug console):

> failed to load resource : ....../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

So somehow the request to the `admin-ajax.php` file isn't successful. I have cross checked these things:

1. the url to `admin-ajax.php` is correct and no issues there
2. its not just 'my own scripts' which doesn't work, i've buddypress installed and all ajax requests from buddypress also give the same error
3. i directly typed in the url of `admin-ajax.php` into browser and instead of getting 0 (the expected output), google chrome says 'no data received'.

Is it some configuration on server end?? If yes then what do i say to the hosting support guys?

BTW, if it matters, the site is hosted on wpengine..

Any help is really appreciated

**UPDATE :**
the browser dev tools screenshot :
[image]

Comment: What does your error log say, and what error code is being returned? It's likely a 500 error not a 404

Comment: The hosting control panel interface at wpengine is different than cPanel, so i can't be sure, but when i go to the error logs, it says 'error log is empty'. No error code is returned, google chrome dev tools console says 'failed to load resource .... ' .And yes you are right, most likely it wont be a 404 issue, removed that tag.

Comment: Open your browser’s dev tools, then the _Network_ tab and look at the HTTP response headers. What exactly do you get there?

Comment: Well, it simply says '(failed)', i've added the screenshot in the question, the image appears too small here, you will have to right click, copy image url and open that url to actually read the text in image. Sorry for the trouble, i dont know if there's a better way to attach images here..

Comment: UPDATE: any ajax requests wont work, not even the ones in wp-admin. e.g: adding a widget doesn't work !!! Trying to uninstall plugins one-by-one and check...

Comment: click on an entry to see more information about it such as the response code, the URL requested in full, the parameters sent to the server and those received etc, as well as the full http response from the server. If it says empty response or something similar try it with WP_DEBUG turned on. Also +1 for screenshots =]

Comment: I was getting the error code 500, failing to load the admin-ajax.php
I updated my php version from 5 to 7 and it worked.

Comment: Besides usual 503 solving methods try to disable SSL encryption on your hosting (and plugins like "simple SSL"!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes finally the problem was that the hosting provider had blocked the admin-ajax.php file saying that this file was receiving too many request, and requests to this file bypasses cache , hence it was causing problems on server  :)

So now i'll have to 'convince' them to turn it back on.

Thank you all for helping..