# fail to load /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php locally

Tags: ajax

I have the same problem as [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106252/failed-to-load-wp-admin-admin-ajax-php), in that all ajax functionality has suddenly stopped working.

In the browser dev tools it gives the error as failed to load resource for wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

With the previous question the solution was that wp-engine had blocked access to admin-ajax.php, but in my case I'm working locally (with MAMP), and I'm not aware of any changes I've made that could affect it.

I would have added a comment to the previous question but I don't have the points.

Comment: Did you already try to add `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);` to your `wp-config.php`?

Comment: What is trying to use the AJAX API?

Comment: Sven, just tried that, no change. s_ha_dum, I have a script on the front end that works with ajax (and has done without problem for months) which I haven't changed recently, and if I go into the admin pages lots of things work with ajax (e.g. dragging widgets in and out of the sidebar) but are giving the same message, that they fail to load admin-ajax.php.

Comment: Which error precisely? What is body of Ajax response (can be inspected using browser's dev tools)? Is it generating any errors in server logs?

Comment: Sorry, things don't "suddenly" stop working. Something has changed. Something happened. You need to work out what. Server (OS) change or update? Server crash? Software install or update-- theme, plugin, WordPress itself, PHP, something? Check your logs. Post [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: I have finally tracked it down to a plug-in issue. It took me quite a while to work out because, ironically enough, it was the debugging plug-in I use which was responsible. I now have it deactivated and am waiting to hear back from the developer...